# IF inside where clause - SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can I have a if statement inside a where clause as in the follwing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM product p
          INNER JOIN product_to_vendor pv
        ON pv.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE pv.vendor_id = @vendorId AND p.site_id = @siteId AND
            IF (@productStatus < 4)
        BEGIN 
            p.[rank] = @productStatus 
        END
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_to_vendor pv
        ON pv.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE     pv.vendor_id = @vendorId 
      AND p.site_id = @siteId 
      AND (@productStatus < 4 AND p.[rank] = @productStatus)
```

I not sure about your requirements, but here it is showing how `if-else` can be constructed from boolean logic. Just assume the if `(condition)` is just another statement for `AND`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now only i got the way to do it. thanks again.